# Reading after disassembly

Tags: assembly

When I disassemble code with gdb, I get lines with the following format:

> 3164d4:       b8 00 00 03 10          mov    $0x121,%ecx

The first column is the address of the instruction, the third the operation to perform and the last the source and destination. But what does the second column represent?

Comment: I see at least 8 columns; which one(s) do you mean?

Comment: The middle content is the actual bytes that represent that instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "second column" you mean, in your example, the "b8 00 00 03 10", that's the machine language (in hexadecimal) of the instruction -- the values that are stored in memory.

Comment: if I type print *(int *) 0x3164d4, I get 184, which, in hex is b8. Where do the other bytes (00 00 03 10) come from?

Comment: `0x3164d4` is just the starting adress of the complete instruction - this particular `mov` requires 5 bytes, you will find them at the succeeding addresses. If you disassemble the next instruction, you will see that it starts at `0x3164d9`